# Kubernetes, Prometheus my custom metric not found but in config exist

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, http-status-code-404, prometheus, metrics

I followed this [THIS](https://piotrminkowski.com/2020/11/05/spring-boot-autoscaling-on-kubernetes/) tutorial. I stuck on chapter "INSTALL PROMETHEUS ADAPTER ON KUBERNETES"

I before installed prometheus and after adapter with this tut.

Loogs from adapter.

```
I1201 18:29:51.064522       1 shared_informer.go:204] Caches are synced for client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::client-ca-file 
I1201 18:29:51.064793       1 tlsconfig.go:157] loaded client CA [0/"client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::client-ca-file,client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file"]: "kubernetes" [] issuer="<self>" (2020-11-26 13:25:15 +0000 UTC to 2030-11-24 13:25:15 +0000 UTC (now=2020-12-01 18:29:51.064776377 +0000 UTC))
I1201 18:29:51.064996       1 tlsconfig.go:179] loaded serving cert ["serving-cert::/tmp/cert/apiserver.crt::/tmp/cert/apiserver.key"]: "localhost@1606847390" [serving] validServingFor=[127.0.0.1,localhost,localhost] issuer="localhost-ca@1606847390" (2020-12-01 17:29:50 +0000 UTC to 2021-12-01 17:29:50 +0000 UTC (now=2020-12-01 18:29:51.064987277 +0000 UTC))
I1201 18:29:51.065289       1 named_certificates.go:52] loaded SNI cert [0/"self-signed loopback"]: "apiserver-loopback-client@1606847390" [serving] validServingFor=[apiserver-loopback-client] issuer="apiserver-loopback-client-ca@1606847390" (2020-12-01 17:29:50 +0000 UTC to 2021-12-01 17:29:50 +0000 UTC (now=2020-12-01 18:29:51.065278277 +0000 UTC))
I1201 18:29:51.065471       1 tlsconfig.go:157] loaded client CA [0/"client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::client-ca-file,client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file"]: "kubernetes" [] issuer="<self>" (2020-11-26 13:25:15 +0000 UTC to 2030-11-24 13:25:15 +0000 UTC (now=2020-12-01 18:29:51.065459677 +0000 UTC))
I1201 18:29:51.065502       1 tlsconfig.go:157] loaded client CA [1/"client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::client-ca-file,client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file"]: "kubernetes" [] issuer="<self>" (2020-11-26 13:25:16 +0000 UTC to 2030-11-24 13:25:16 +0000 UTC (now=2020-12-01 18:29:51.065493477 +0000 UTC))
I1201 18:29:51.065715       1 tlsconfig.go:179] loaded serving cert ["serving-cert::/tmp/cert/apiserver.crt::/tmp/cert/apiserver.key"]: "localhost@1606847390" [serving] validServingFor=[127.0.0.1,localhost,localhost] issuer="localhost-ca@1606847390" (2020-12-01 17:29:50 +0000 UTC to 2021-12-01 17:29:50 +0000 UTC (now=2020-12-01 18:29:51.065704777 +0000 UTC))
I1201 18:29:51.065910       1 named_certificates.go:52] loaded SNI cert [0/"self-signed loopback"]: "apiserver-loopback-client@1606847390" [serving] validServingFor=[apiserver-loopback-client] issuer="apiserver-loopback-client-ca@1606847390" (2020-12-01 17:29:50 +0000 UTC to 2021-12-01 17:29:50 +0000 UTC (now=2020-12-01 18:29:51.065901277 +0000 UTC))
I1201 18:30:24.362727       1 httplog.go:90] GET /healthz: (2.2796ms) 200 [kube-probe/1.16+ 10.1.0.1:53930]
I1201 18:30:25.463080       1 httplog.go:90] GET /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: (2.9747ms) 200 [Go-http-client/2.0 192.168.65.3:46844]
E1201 18:30:25.465710       1 writers.go:105] apiserver was unable to write a JSON response: http2: stream closed
E1201 18:30:25.465953       1 status.go:71] apiserver received an error that is not an metav1.Status: &errors.errorString{s:"http2: stream closed"}
I1201 18:30:25.466586       1 httplog.go:90] GET /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: (2.8732ms) 200 [Go-http-client/2.0 192.168.65.3:46844]
E1201 18:30:25.467206       1 writers.go:105] apiserver was unable to write a JSON response: http2: stream closed
I1201 18:30:25.467753       1 httplog.go:90] GET /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: (7.164101ms) 200 [Go-http-client/2.0 192.168.65.3:46844]
E1201 18:30:25.468083       1 writers.go:118] apiserver was unable to write a fallback JSON response: http2: stream closed
E1201 18:30:25.472221       1 writers.go:105] apiserver was unable to write a JSON response: http2: stream closed
E1201 18:30:25.472609       1 writers.go:105] apiserver was unable to write a JSON response: http2: stream closed
E1201 18:30:25.472730       1 writers.go:105] apiserver was unable to write a JSON response: http2: stream closed
I1201 18:30:25.472909       1 httplog.go:90] GET /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: (1.0713ms) 200 [Go-http-client/2.0 192.168.65.3:46844]
I1201 18:30:25.474640       1 httplog.go:90] GET /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: (1.647ms) 200 [Go-http-client/2.0 192.168.65.3:46844]
E1201 18:30:25.475699       1 status.go:71] apiserver received an error that is not an metav1.Status: &errors.errorString{s:"http2: stream closed"}
I1201 18:30:25.479184       1 httplog.go:90] GET /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: (20.215901ms) 200 [Go-http-client/2.0 192.168.65.3:46844]
E1201 18:30:25.479482       1 writers.go:118] apiserver was unable to write a fallback JSON response: http2: stream closed
E1201 18:30:25.480170       1 status.go:71] apiserver received an error that is not an metav1.Status: &errors.errorString{s:"http2: stream closed"}
E1201 18:30:25.481352       1 status.go:71] apiserver received an error that is not an metav1.Status: &errors.errorString{s:"http2: stream closed"}
E1201 18:30:25.482583       1 status.go:71] apiserver received an error that is not an metav1.Status: &errors.errorString{s:"http2: stream closed"}
I1201 18:30:25.483849       1 httplog.go:90] GET /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: (25.682902ms) 200 [Go-http-client/2.0 192.168.65.3:46844]
E1201 18:30:25.485396       1 writers.go:118] apiserver was unable to write a fallback JSON response: http2: stream closed
E1201 18:30:25.486509       1 writers.go:118] apiserver was unable to write a fallback JSON response: http2: stream closed
E1201 18:30:25.487726       1 writers.go:118] apiserver was unable to write a fallback JSON response: http2: stream closed
I1201 18:30:25.488748       1 httplog.go:90] GET /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: (17.878101ms) 200 [Go-http-client/2.0 192.168.65.3:46844]
I1201 18:30:25.489839       1 httplog.go:90] GET /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: (18.999301ms) 200 [Go-http-client/2.0 192.168.65.3:46844]
I1201 18:30:25.491108       1 httplog.go:90] GET /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: (19.478801ms) 200 [Go-http-client/2.0 192.168.65.3:46844]
I1201 18:30:26.476227       1 httplog.go:90] GET /openapi/v2: (1.2015ms) 404 [ 192.168.65.3:46868]
I1201 18:30:28.165256       1 httplog.go:90] GET /healthz: (190.7µs) 200 [kube-probe/1.16+ 10.1.0.1:53966]
I1201 18:30:34.360535       1 httplog.go:90] GET /healthz: (116.3µs) 200 [kube-probe/1.16+ 10.1.0.1:54020]
I1201 18:30:36.350376       1 httplog.go:90] GET /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1?timeout=32s: (4.363901ms) 200 [kube-controller-manager/v1.16.6 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/e7f962b/system:serviceaccount:kube-system:resourcequota-controller 192.168.65.3:46868]
I1201 18:30:37.315883       1 httplog.go:90] GET /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1?timeout=32s: (2.5138ms) 200 [kube-controller-manager/v1.16.6 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/e7f962b/controller-discovery 192.168.65.3:46868]
I1201 18:30:37.329496       1 httplog.go:90] GET /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/pods/%2A/http_server_requests_seconds_count_sum?labelSelector=app%3Dauth-server: (5.072601ms) 404 [kube-controller-manager/v1.16.6 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/e7f962b/system:serviceaccount:kube-system:horizontal-pod-autoscaler 192.168.65.3:46868]
I1201 18:30:38.165664       1 httplog.go:90] GET /healthz: (1.2018ms) 200 [kube-probe/1.16+ 10.1.0.1:54046]
I1201 18:30:44.361064       1 httplog.go:90] GET /healthz: (73.5µs) 200 [kube-probe/1.16+ 10.1.0.1:54108]
I1201 18:30:44.960512       1 httplog.go:90] GET /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: (1.0876ms) 200 [Go-http-client/2.0 192.168.65.3:46844]
I1201 18:30:44.961265       1 httplog.go:90] GET /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: (2.1336ms) 200 [Go-http-client/2.0 192.168.65.3:46844]
I1201 18:30:44.961449       1 httplog.go:90] GET /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: (1.61ms) 200 [Go-http-client/2.0 192.168.65.3:46844]
E1201 18:30:44.961861       1 writers.go:105] apiserver was unable to write a JSON response: http2: stream closed
E1201 18:30:44.961923       1 status.go:71] apiserver received an error that is not an metav1.Status: &errors.errorString{s:"http2: stream closed"}
E1201 18:30:44.962376       1 writers.go:105] apiserver was unable to write a JSON response: http2: stream closed
E1201 18:30:44.963100       1 writers.go:118] apiserver was unable to write a fallback JSON response: http2: stream closed
E1201 18:30:44.964224       1 status.go:71] apiserver received an error that is not an metav1.Status: &errors.errorString{s:"http2: stream closed"}
E1201 18:30:44.965232       1 writers.go:118] apiserver was unable to write a fallback JSON response: http2: stream closed
I1201 18:30:44.966366       1 httplog.go:90] GET /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: (5.682901ms) 200 [Go-http-client/2.0 192.168.65.3:46844]
I1201 18:30:44.967578       1 httplog.go:90] GET /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: (8.177501ms) 200 [Go-http-client/2.0 192.168.65.3:46844]
I1201 18:30:48.168761       1 httplog.go:90] GET /healthz: (2.2637ms) 200 [kube-probe/1.16+ 10.1.0.1:54138]
I1201 18:30:48.237637       1 httplog.go:90] GET /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1?timeout=32s: (1.4318ms) 200 [kube-controller-manager/v1.16.6 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/e7f962b/system:serviceaccount:kube-system:generic-garbage-collector 192.168.65.3:46868]
```

In configmap prometheus-adapter on kubernetes I have:

```
- metricsQuery: sum(<<.Series>>{<<.LabelMatchers>>,uri=~"/persons.*"}) by
(<<.GroupBy>>)
  name:
    as: http_server_requests_seconds_count_sum
    matches: ^http_server_requests_seconds_count(.*)
  resources:
    overrides:
      kubernetes_namespace:
        resource: namespace
      kubernetes_pod_name:
        resource: pod
  seriesQuery: '{__name__=~"^http_server_requests_seconds_.*"}'
```

with many diffrent metrics.

When try create Horizonal Pod Autoscaler with my metric I have: unable to get metric ...

In command: kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1"
I have many metrics so I think connection is ok.

[image: response]

But my metric isn't there and when I use this command (DOWN), the same error could not find metric

```
kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/pods/*/http_server_requests_seconds_count_sum"
```

Comment: Did you configure the service on a pod and with the respective ports?

Comment: @Felipe If you mean service when I need HPS
https://pastebin.com/YNuXJSAb
if no, what service ?

Comment: No. I mean the k8s service that expose a pod to outside. Like in the example https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/blob/master/examples/example-app/example-app.yaml . Your tutorial uses Helm. I think it is better to use the original prometheus images.

Comment: @Felipe https://ctrlv.cz/8UHL

Comment: I never used that image however it is a good one. I have used the `prom/prometheus` and I just configured a service and rest web service with the ports and it worked. https://hub.docker.com/r/prom/prometheus/